# jQuery tools tabs fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used [jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html) to create a tabs setup, and I would like to incorporate the fade effect, but when I try to do so, it bombs out, here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#flowtabs").tabs("#flowpanes > div", { history: true, effect: 'fade' });
});
```

I am assuming that it's because I am also enabling the tabs history?

I am kinda new to all of this, so please be patient! :-)

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with fade when using the jQueryTools tooltips.  It was with the downloaded version.  I plugged into their CDN version as a sanity check, and the fades started working properly.

To get the most recent CDN link, visit the [download page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) and look for the *Quick Start* section